# How to save coordinates to index in Elasticsearch and use them in Kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have this DataFrame:

```
    Title   Authors               Institutions          
0   a      ['name_1', 'name_2']   [['Osaka Univ.', '34.82,135.52']] 
1   b      ['name_1']             [['Tohoku Univ.', '38.25,140.87'], ['Kobe Univ.', '34.72,135.23']]
2   c         …         
3   d         …             
4   e         …
```

which I convert to a JSON file:

```
df_output.to_json('output.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

Getting:

```
{"Title": "a","Authors":["name_1", "name_2"],"Institutions":[["Osaka 
                                              University", "34.82,135.52"]]}
{"Title": "b","Authors":["name_1"],"Institutions":[['Tohoku Univ.', "38.25, 
                                   140.87"], ['Kobe Univ.', "34.72, 135.23"]]}              
...
```

So index this JSON into Elasticsearch to then search them by Title.

```
import requests
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

url= 'https://"""my_session_in_amazon""".amazonaws.com'
es = Elasticsearch([url])

filename = 'C:/xx/xxx/output.json'
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open(filename, 'r')]
helpers.bulk(es, data, index='title', doc_type='HEP_books')
```

But then in Kibana I dont know how to access the institutions coordinates to plot a map of the institutions

Comment: You can leave id blank and ES will create an ID for you.

Comment: and the body is ok?  Can I use just one json file instead of one per book?

Comment: Your sample JSON output has a key of `"Tile"`, not `"Title"`.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample data frame you pasted, it looks like 'Institutions' is an array which contains both the institution name and the coordinates of it. this will make it impossible to plot those coordinates on a map, as elasticsearch dynamic mapping would consider 'Institutions' as a string/keyword, and not a geo_point/number.

The first step you need is to extract the coordinates to a dedicated field - for example Institutions.geo . You can use [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) in order to extract it and modify the docs.

Second, you need to specify in Elasticsearch template for those indices that Institutions.geo (for example) is a [geo_point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html), and create a new index for this data.

Third, after the data is clean, in a separate dedicated field, and have the right mapping, you need to refresh fields list in kibana, in order for kibana to recognise the new Institution.geo field.

Fourth, after refresh the mappings in kibana, you can go ahead and create a new Map visualisation based on this data.

Comment: Thanks so much. But I have a question: per each title (row in the dataframe) I can have more than one institution. How can I reorganize my dataframe to get those coordinates separate?

Comment: If you plan to have multiple institutes per title, then you have an array of locations per a single entry. Although this is supported in Elasticsearch, Kibana will not work well with lists/arrays. Consider breaking the data to smaller documents, each with a single geo location - just 'flatten' the data